# How can I force a batch file to move onto the next command while previous is still executing?

Tags: cmd

Need to control what a running program (that runs within a cmd window) does from a batch file. My closest solution is to have the console from which it runs, run commands stored in a text file that only has contents during update periods via a scheduled task.  However it either won't move to the next command or if I use /b it seems to use a separate console (even though it's in the same console window).  It won't affect the running program.

The code below based on some reading from this site.  I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.

```
start /b bedrock_server.exe

GOTO :START

:START

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 180 >nul

echo "checked"

type command.txt|cmd

GOTO :START
```

Ok so the idea is that command.txt will have the word 'stop' in it so the server stops. But with the /b switch, bedrock_server is isolated from any new commands, and cmd asks me "more?" because stop by itself is only a command to bedrock_server.

I need to stop the bedrock server to perform updates, nicely, not forcefully, in an automated way. I will accept workarounds, but have already considered automation tools that simulate user input, and for now I will not employ them.

Comment: `start` always starts a new process (althoug it runs in the same window with the `/b` switch). Sadly, `cmd` has no method for communication between different processes (`cmd` instances) You need help from another language (maybe [VB Script](https://ss64.com/vb/), which has a `sendkey` command)

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work for my purposes.

Comment: What about the [`waitfor` command](https://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html), could that help you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in a new cmd Process

```
cmd.exe /k [command]
```